# How to create multiple image preview

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I hope someone can help me, as i have be wondering which route to take for a couple of days now, i want to create a image preview section to my website, which is for Windows, Doors etc, so what i am after is a section that has multiple options which say (For example) Door1, Door2, Door3 & Side 1, Side 2, Side 3, with a box underneath which shows the images, so lets say for example i click Door1 (door 1 will show) then i click Side 3, and side 3 will show next to door1, I hope this makes sense ? im really struggling with which language to approach this in, any help, guidance or if someone has already done this, would be of great help.....as its been on my mind for a while now.

UPDATE - Found this script which kinda does what i want, but i cant seem to replace the text with an image, where it says "div content changed -worked" i want to display an image instead. 
Here is what i found, can anyone help suggest how to replace the text with an image.

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function ReplaceContentInContainer(id,content) {
var container = document.getElementById(id);
container.innerHTML = content;
}
//--></script>

 <div 
 id="example1div" 
 style="border-style:solid; 
      padding:10px;
      width:400px; 
      text-align:center;">
TEXT TEST TEST TEXT.
</div>
<a href="javascript:ReplaceContentInContainer('example1div','DIV CONTENT CHANGED - WORKED')">
Click me to replace the content in the container.
</a>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any able to help with the ammended question ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have static page, which you will edit manually, by editing HTML by hand than you don't need PHP. Just find some Lightbox JavaScript plugin and check out how it works. There are many of them.

But if you want your web page to have back-end where you can login and administrate those images you should go with some CMS. WordPress would be easiest to implement and most popular, IMHO.

Comment: Hi MilanG, good shout on the Lightbox, ill look into that, thanks mate, if it does what im after ill post back and accept answer.

Comment: If you go with WordPress, check out for WP light box plugins. With them you don't have to deal JS, but they should work out of box.

Comment: I have updated my original post, don't know if you can help at all ?